# Does DBI dbWriteTable have a row limit 1457?

Tags: r, sql-server, dataframe, limit, r-dbi

Using R and troubleshooting an error, I discovered an interesting limit [that I seemingly have] with DBI::dbWriteTable.

I am trying to write a large data `my.df` frame to a sql server.

`dim(my.df)` = > 19391    18

```
dbWriteTable(conn = connection, name = "name_of_table", value = my.df, row.names = FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

but this fails with error (seems to be truncated):

```
Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values) : 
     nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Se
```

Now the interesting thing is that restricting the rows to `my.df[1:1456,]` works, no problem:

```
dbWriteTable(conn = connection, name = "name_of_table", value = my.df[1:1456,], row.names = FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

But now try `my.df[1:1457,]` and the previous error returns:

```
dbWriteTable(conn = connection, name = "name_of_table", value = my.df[1:1457,], row.names = FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

Checking that 1457 isn't a problematic row, the following passes:

```
dbWriteTable(conn = connection, name = "name_of_table", value = my.df[1457,], row.names = FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

I'm not sure if this is a restriction in R or from the server. Does anybody have any insights into what is causing this error and the best way to work around it?

Apologies that I cannot supply the server connection details or the data in my data-frame.

Thank you.

EDIT>

An example of a line from this dataframe is:
[image]

Or the dput:

`dput(one_row.df)`:

```
structure(list(name = 2272L, name = 0.067, name = 1, name = 1, 
    name = 1, name = 0.067, name = FALSE, name = FALSE, name = TRUE, 
    name = TRUE, name = TRUE, name = TRUE, name = TRUE, name = TRUE, 
    name = TRUE, name = 0.402, name = structure(1530282001.49934, class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), name = "0"), .Names = c("name", "name", "name", 
"name", "name", "name", "name", "name", "name", "name", "name", 
"name", "name", "name", "name", "name", "name", "name"), row.names = 5L, class = "data.frame")
```

**SEMI REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE**

With the above example row I replicate just that row a number of times and use that within in writetable. This time 1024 rows passes but 1025 rows fails as seen in the below output. I have also included their sizes.

```
> dbWriteTable(connection, name = "name_of_table", value = mefa:::rep.data.frame(one_row.df, times = 1024), row.names = FALSE, append=TRUE)
> dbWriteTable(connection, name = "name_of_table", value = mefa:::rep.data.frame(one_row.df, times = 1025), row.names = FALSE, append=TRUE)
Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Se                                                    
> mefa:::rep.data.frame(one_row.df, times = 1024) %>% object.size()
105808 bytes
> mefa:::rep.data.frame(one_row.df, times = 1025) %>% object.size()
105952 bytes
```

The size of the original df rows are:

- `object.size(my.df[1:1456,])` = 154464 bytes which passed
- `object.size(my.df[1:1457,])` = 154608 bytes which failed

EDIT2> including the server connection details

```
connnection <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                          Driver   = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                          Server   = "server-name",
                          Database = "db",
                          UID      = "db_user",
                          PWD      = "db_password",
                          Port     = 1433)
```

Comment: Showing some sample data might help, because then readers of your question could estimate how much memory 1457 rows of your data frame would represent.

Comment: I have already write tables with 30 columns and over 200,000 rows in a SQLite DB using DBI, so maybe the limit is in Microsoft ODBC Driver. Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms719628(v=vs.85)

Comment: I use way more rows than that with it. Way more. Are you doing this over ODBC? I experienced a problem once where there was a limit in the ODBC driver that had to be changed to allow me to read more than a certain number of rows.

Comment: >@Hack-R I am indeed doing over ODBC, how did you change that limit?
>TimBiegeleisen that makes sense, I will work on generating some sample data and recreating a (semi) reproducible problem with it. 
>CarlosEduardoLagosta I will explore  that document. Interestingly I only run into this limit on cloud linux virtual enviroment -- from my local windows RStudio session, I have no limitations/ problems to upload.
Thank you all.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen in case this helps in the mean time `object.size(my.df[1:1456,]) = 154464 bytes`
`object.size(my.df[1:1457,]) = 154608 bytes`

Comment: @Parfait I am using odbc. I've included the connection assignment in an edit in the OP. I was unable to run the `VARCHAR(Max)`,  `VARBINARY`, `EXEC sp_help <table_name>` commands within R - is there another way to get these values?

Comment: @Parfait running the `EXEC sp_help` query gives:
        Name = table_name       Owner = AccessOwner         Type  = user table  Created_datetime = 2018-06-20 17:46:44

Comment: @Parfait I queried `EXEC sp_help table_name`